# Python dictionary operation using percentage sign

Tags: python, list, dictionary, percentage

I have a list containing 2 dictionaries:

```
>>> x
[{'sby_0': 'sb0'}, {'sby_1': 'sb1'}]
```

I want to get the 2nd dictonary's item using percentage sign:

```
i = 1
x[1]["sby_%s" %i]
```

but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine:

```
>>> x = [{'sby_0': 'sb0'}, {'sby_1': 'sb1'}]
>>> i = 1
>>> x[1]["sby_%s" %i]
'sb1'
```

However, I'd use `%d` instead of `%s` since `i` is a number.

The error in the code you didn't post is that you used `"sby_%s", i` instead of `"sby_%s" % i`. `%` performs string formatting (what you want) while `,` creates a tuple (what you do not want in this case)

Comment: I get this: `>>> x[1]["sby_%s", i]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    x[1]["sby_%i", i]
KeyError: ('sby_%i', 1)`

Comment: You wrote `,` instead of `%` - and your dict does not have a key `('sby_%i', 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code:

```
In [6]: x = [{'sby_0': 'sb0'}, {'sby_1': 'sb1'}]

In [7]: i = 1

In [8]: x[1]['sby_%s' % i]
Out[8]: 'sb1'
```

**edit** The error message you've posted in the comments says `x[1]["sby_%i", i]`. The problem there is the comma; it should be replaced the with the percent sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = [{'sby_0': 'sb0'}, {'sby_1': 'sb1'}]
>>> i = 1
>>> x[1]
{'sby_1': 'sb1'}
>>> x[1]['sby_%s' % i]
'sb1'
```

It works as intended. Perhaps expand on your question and post more information about your usage.